# Input only above a "layer-node"

Tags: input, godot

using `get_node("xyz").input_pickable = false` usually works fine for me to (dis)able a node's collision shape.

What I'm looking for is a node I could place all over "the whole screen" and have everything below (z axis-wise) unpickable as well as everything above pickable. A scenario would be a popup-window overlapping all kinds of input-elements which shouldn't be clickable while said window is open...

Is there any way to apply such a "layer"? This would be quite convenient.

EDIT:

Obviously it works fine with normal buttons and a Panel in between. My custom-made buttons built from  Node2D --> Area2D --> CollisionShape2D  won't though...

Any idea why that could be? Do Panel and CollisionShape2D seem "incompatible" here somehow?

Comment: Read up on Control’s mouse filter options and accept event method, SceneTree’s set input as handled method, and most importantly how input propagates through the scene tree. Great explanations of these are available at: [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/index.html). If you need more specific help be sure to update the post. Good luck.

Comment: There already exists a [`Popup`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_popup.html) control node that handles this for you. One of its child classes (`PopupDialog`, `PopupPanel`, `WindowDialog`) might be more appropriate depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your input, guys!

I aimed to build buttons all on my own, and it eventually worked out fine in terms of flexible animating etc. I only later stumbled over this problem of implementing them into a more complex context.

Now I guess I should use "on board" buttons as a base and then try to pimp them with my own designs... probably the best way to approach such elements. The buttons Godot offers work as I want them to when putting a panel in between - the one below won't trigger. I just couldn't make that work for with straight collision shapes - neither of them triggers...